# how to retrieve data from dynamically added rows in html table and how to insert them into database

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
//html code here
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    var i=1;
    function addRow()//function that add the row
    {
          var tbl = document.getElementById('table1');
          var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
          var iteration = lastRow - 1;
          var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);

      var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
      var el = document.createElement('input');
      el.type = 'text';
      el.name = 'name_' + i;
      el.id = 'name_' + i;
      el.size = 20;
      el.maxlength = 20;
      firstCell.appendChild(el);

      var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
      var el2 = document.createElement('input');
      el2.type = 'text';
      el2.name = 'address_' + i;
      el2.id = 'address_' + i;
      el2.size = 20;
      el2.maxlength = 20;
      secondCell.appendChild(el2);

      var thirdCell = row.insertCell(2);
      var el3 = document.createElement('input');
      el3.type = 'text';
      el3.name = 'contactNum_' + i;
      el3.id = 'contactNum_' + i;
      el3.size = 20;
      el3.maxlength = 20;
      thirdCell.appendChild(el3);
     // alert(i);

      frm.h.value=i;
      i++;
    //  alert(i);
}
</script>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title></head>

<body>
<form action="submit.php" method="POST" name="frm" id="frm" enctype="multiform/form-data">
<table width="40%" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="table1">
  <tr>
    <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
    <td><strong>Address</strong> </td>
    <td><strong>Contact Num</strong> </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><input name="name_0" type="text" id="name_0" size="20" maxlength="20" /></td>
    <td><input name="address_0" type="text" id="address_0" size="20" maxlength="20" /></td>
    <td><input name="contactNum_0" type="text" id="contactNum_0" size="20" maxlength="12" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow();" />
<input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
<label>
<input name="h" type="hidden" id="h" value="0" />
</label>
</form>

</body>
</html>
and 
here is my submit.php
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", '');
mysqli_select_db($con,"test");

if(isset($_POST['submit']))

{
$num =$_POST['h'];

for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)

{

        $name       = $_POST["name_$i"];
        $address    = $_POST["address_$i"];
        $contactNum = $_POST["contactNum_$i"];

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `com`(`name`, `add`, contact) Values('$name', '$address', '$contactNum')");

}

echo "<h1>Done!</h1>";
}
else
{
    echo "not inserted";
}
?>
```

Comment: okay where is your `select` block? and where you struck ?

Comment: Without any guidance from you as to what's wrong with the code, it is very difficult to pin down any issues. Apart from the fact that your code is vulnerable to sql injection attack, I can't really see any error. There is room for improvement, though.

Comment: @rohit FYI, 1. you button name and `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` is different you should use `S`(capital letter). 2. `$num` is initialize value is `0` so while chcking the for loop the condition is `$i<$num` (0<0) thats the problem with inserting.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: tq so much@LifeTimeProgrammer

Answer (score 0):

**INSERT** is working good, i can change something in your code

> 1.if(isset($_POST['submit'])) //Submit (capital S)
>
> 2.$i<=$num // change to  <=

**`PHP` code always first block of your page.**

```
<?php
        session_start();
        
        if(isset($_POST['Submit']))
        {
            $num =$_POST['h'];
            
            for($i=0;$i<=$num;$i++)
            {
                $name       = $_POST["name_$i"];
                $address    = $_POST["address_$i"];
                $contactNum = $_POST["contactNum_$i"];
                
                mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO `com`(`name`, `add`, contact) Values('$name', '$address', '$contactNum')");
            }
        }
        ?>
            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
            <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            var i=1;
            function addRow()//function that add the row
            {
                  var tbl = document.getElementById('table1');
                  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
                  var iteration = lastRow - 1;
                  var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);
        
              var firstCell = row.insertCell(0);
              var el = document.createElement('input');
              el.type = 'text';
              el.name = 'name_' + i;
              el.id = 'name_' + i;
              el.size = 20;
              el.maxlength = 20;
              firstCell.appendChild(el);
        
              var secondCell = row.insertCell(1);
              var el2 = document.createElement('input');
              el2.type = 'text';
              el2.name = 'address_' + i;
              el2.id = 'address_' + i;
              el2.size = 20;
              el2.maxlength = 20;
              secondCell.appendChild(el2);
        
              var thirdCell = row.insertCell(2);
              var el3 = document.createElement('input');
              el3.type = 'text';
              el3.name = 'contactNum_' + i;
              el3.id = 'contactNum_' + i;
              el3.size = 20;
              el3.maxlength = 20;
              thirdCell.appendChild(el3);
             // alert(i);
        
              frm.h.value=i;
              i++;
            //  alert(i);
        }
        </script>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Untitled Document</title></head>
        
        <body>
        <form action="" method="POST" name="frm" id="frm" enctype="multiform/form-data">
        <table width="40%" border="2" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="table1">
          <tr>
            <td><strong>Name</strong></td>
            <td><strong>Address</strong> </td>
            <td><strong>Contact Num</strong> </td>
          </tr>
         <tr>
            <td><input name="name_0" type="text" id="name_0" size="20" maxlength="20" /></td>
            <td><input name="address_0" type="text" id="address_0" size="20" maxlength="20" /></td>
            <td><input name="contactNum_0" type="text" id="contactNum_0" size="20" maxlength="12" /></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <input type="button" value="Add" onclick="addRow();" />
        <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
        <label>
        <input name="h" type="hidden" id="h" value="0" />
        </label>
        </form>
        
        </body>
        </html>
        <!--and 
        here is my submit.php-->
```